# Alexa Simulator "hangs"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm in my baby-steps in Alexa Skills development and I'm stuck in the testing part. It seems that the simulator just hangs. The bubbles wont go away and I dont get any some sort of a response. I made sure that the skill is configured using EN-US and that the Lambda function is hosted on US-East (N.Virgina). Not entirely sure what to do from here.

[image]

Comment: We don't use [solved] devices in titles here. Instead, use the acceptance system - self-answers are very welcome on this platform. Click the tick mark when the system lets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me 2 days to locate the issue. As it turns out ADGuard is doing more than it's suppose to do. I had it completely disabled yet the Simulator did not want to work. Only after killing it's process entirely did the Simulator finally start to work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had stop fiddler running and it started working,
This was the error I was getting,

```
HTTP/1.0 200 This buggy server did not return headers
```